# One-to-many and many-to-many relationship between the same entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Say I want to model a relationship between users and auctions. A user can host an auction in which other users can bid in, while he can also bid in auctions of other users. So I want a ***User*** table, an ***Auction*** table with a foreign key reference to the User table, and an ***AuctionBidders*** table.

What do I have to add/change in the code below or in the OnModelCreating() method to make it work?

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Auction> Auctions { get; set; }
}

public class Auction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User Host { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Bidders { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that one action can have only have one Host, but the same user can be a Host for many auctions, you have to add relations for Host too

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
     [InverseProperty(nameof(Auction.Host))]
     public ICollection<Auction> Hosts { get; set; }
 
    public ICollection<Auction> Auctions { get; set; }
}

public class Auction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int HostId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(HostId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(User.Hosts))]
    public User Host { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

ef core 5+ will create the third table for you but I would prefer to add it explicetely since you have non standard db structrure

```
public class AuctionUser
{   
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
   
     public int AuctionId { get; set; }
      
     [ForeignKey(nameof(AuctionId))]
      [InverseProperty("Users")]
     public virtual Auction Auction { get; set; }

      public int UserId { get; set; }

      [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
      [InverseProperty("Auctions")]
      public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If a user can bid on many options other than his owned one, one may assume a m-m relationship between user and auction hence the 3rd table mentioned in the question, namely,  AuctionBidders table.

Comment: @NoChance Thanks for  a feedback. I am just assuming that one action can have only one Host, otherwise it will be needed one more table for hosts.

Comment: Yup, makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @Serge looks like it needs more constraints to work. The error is: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_AuctionUser_Users_UsersId' on table 'AuctionUser' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.